# Return the progress to the template each value change in Django

Tags: django, ajax, python-3.x, django-templates

I want to show the progress of the task going in the back-end in order let the user know that the work is still in progress.

I have ajax call to a function to get the final value. In back end it will take lot of time to complete the job, but each time i have the progress of the job in one variable i want to show the values of this variable in the front end.

For example my ajax function is

```
def ajax_call(request):
    j = 0
    for i in range(1,10000):
        j += i
    res = {'data': j}
    return JsonResponse(res, safe=False)
```

As we know it will return the final value of j.  But i want to show the value of j in the front end in each change. Is there any simple way to do this using celery or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't show every value of `j` without ending the request, so, ending the process itself.

But, you can do some workarounds like having a status field in some model to get that value from there and pass it on to your user, this should work with a celery task or whatever.

Some simple code (not tested)

**In your models.py**

```py
class TaskStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_ONEPERCENT = 'zeropct'
    STATUS_ONEPERCENT = 'onepct'
    STATUS_TENPERCENT = 'tenpct'
    CHOICES_STATUS = (
        (STATUS_ZEROPERCENT, _('0%')),
        (STATUS_ONEPERCENT, _('1%')),
        (STATUS_TENPERCENT, _('10%')),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), 
        verbose_name=_('User task owner'),
        related_name='tasks_statuses')
    task_uuid = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Taks unique ID'), maxlength=50)
    status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Task status'), 
        choices=CHOICES_STATUS, 
        default=CHOICES_STATUS[0][0])
```

**In your views**

```py
def create_taskstatus(request):
    newts = TaskStatus.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        task_uuid=uuid.uuid1())
    res = {
        'tsuuid': newts.task_uuid,
        'status': newts.status, 
        'status_hr': newts.get_status_display()  # human readable status
    }
    return JsonReponse(res, safe=False)

def get_taskstatus(request, tsuuid):
    user_task = get_user_model().tasks_statuses.get(task_uuid=tsuuid)
    res = {
        'tsuuid': user_task.task_uuid, 
        'status': user_task.status, 
        'status_hr': user_task.get_status_display()  # human readable status
    }
    return JsonReponse(res, safe=False)
```

Your flow will be, make an ajax call to `create_taskstatus` and use the returned `tsuuid` to query the status of that task making periodic calls to `get_taskstatus` view, be carefull here, if you make calls too often it can overload your server.

Your current task code must receive the task uuid and take care of updating `TaskStatus.status` value in order to update it as desired:

```py
def ajax_call(request, taskuuid):
    user_task = get_user_model().tasks_statuses.get(task_uuid=tsuuid)
    j = 0
    for i in range(1,10000):
        j += i
        if j == 100:
            user_task.status = TaskStatus.STATUS_ONEPERCENT
            user_task.save()
        elif j == 1000:
            user_task.status = TaskStatus.STATUS_TENPERCENT
            user_task.save()
    res = {'data': j}
    return JsonResponse(res, safe=False)
```

This is just an approach and you must tune the code to fit your needs, I'm just hoping this drives you on a way to a solution.

---

On the other hand you can take advantage of websockets and use [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [centrifugo](https://centrifugal.github.io/centrifugo/) to push the updates to a channel in a user socket connection but I will not give a go if you just need this functionality, lots overhead here just for this.